# Is there an easy way to up or downgrade from Ubuntu 22.04 Jammy to focal Fossa?

Tags: 20.04, system-installation

I have installed Ubuntu 22.04 Jammy, and was trying to install ROS1 on it. After a long time of looking for the errors during installation I found out that ROS1 could only be installed on Focal Fossa ( stupid situation, nobody has mentioned it on ROS website in a clear form)

So now I need to switch between the two Ubuntus. I have installed my Ubuntu on an external HDD of 1 TB.

I recreated the bootable USB from Ubuntu focal Fossa, but when I restart the laptop and press F12, and choose the USB device, it only takes me to the dual boot menu, without giving me the possibility of installation. I have not formatted my external HDD. should I do that? since when I open it on Windows I see only 500 GB free space.

Comment: Ok thank you , so how can I format my external hdd from current Ubuntu jammy and install the other one? Currently it does not allow to bring the install option up

Comment: I think I was not clear, Ubuntu is installed on external hdd. How do I remove this Ubuntu when I'm on windows 10 which is on laptop hdd?

Comment: When I restart, and press F12, while the external hdd is connected, the Ubuntu installation does not come up

Comment: Yes, restore your backups.  You can re-install a Ubuntu Desktop release without loss of files, and having *manually installed* packages auto-reinstall (if from Ubuntu repositories) which can be used (*you're just using an older release in the install*), but problems can be experienced going to older releases as it's unsupported. You need to check each package manually to ensure it can deal with data touched by a newer version, as some (*very few actually but if you value your data you need to check!*) to ensure no ill side effects will be encountered first  (ie. homework required)

Comment: I think you did not notice my point: How do I wipe the Ubuntu jammy from my external HDD? when I connect this hard drive with my Windows 10 on, I see only 500MB empty disk, and formatting it does not bring the 1TB back to reinstall Ubuntu Fossa

Comment: You mention *formatting* but don't specify what you formatted.  You can format partitions (ie. divisions of a drive thus can be any size less than the total capacity of the total drive), or create a new partition table.  If you've lost part of the capacity of your drive (however it is), I'd firstly validate the health of the drive using SMART, then create a new partition table on the drive so you're starting again. You can then format partitions using that new partition table & create new partitions up to total size.

Comment: I have windows 10 installed on my laptop,and Ubuntu on my external hdd. I want to remove Ubuntu from my external hdd. But when I plug the external hdd I don't see the contents of Ubuntu.  I only see an empty hdd with a small volume. So how do I remove it? Using DISK on USB live? Should I create it in windows?

Comment: @Nmath Well I was not familiar with them and someone helped me with them. I used first partition manager of windows to delete the partitions created on external HDD. then used AOMEI to create new partitions