# How to remove Ubuntu Jammy from external HDD and/or replace with Ubuntu Focal Fossa?

Tags: system-installation

I have installed an Ubuntu 20.04 jammy on my external HDD, while I use Windows 10 on my laptop.
Now I have noticed that I have installed the wrong release of Ubuntu and I need to replace it with focal Fossa.

So I overwrote the USB key content with Ubuntu focal fossa .iso file to boot from and to install it on my external HDD.

but when I restart my Windows and hit F12, I only go to the boot menu, and when I hit the USB key ( it is not the first option in the boot list) it opens the dual boot with the usual 3 options : 1-Ubuntu 2- Advanced Ubuntu options 3-Windows boot manager

and there is no "try to install Ubuntu option"

Should I format my External HDD from Ubuntu jammy? is that the root cause? Can I not install an older release on external HDD by overwriting?

update for the second comment : I share the options of writing Ubuntu.iso file in Rufus :

[image]

Comment: What happens if you choose "Ubuntu" and boot from there? You will probably get the "Try Ubuntu" and "install Ubuntu" options. The grub menu hasn't been updated yet, so you get the old one.

Comment: From my reading of your current situation (prior question is [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1446321/is-there-an-easy-way-to-up-or-downgrade-from-ubuntu-20-04-jammy-to-focal-fossa), either your new ISO wasn't written correctly (causing your firmware to return to existing installed options & not offering the Try option), or you didn't verify the ISO and it was corrupted (thus is unbootable).  Did you verify ISO (checksum or https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0) & write to media?

Comment: dear @guiverc Thank you for the points, for your info, I shared the rufus settings writing ISO on USB boot. previous time I guess it was not 4096 byes but 8196 bytes( the next step) but the boot screen always showed ACPI Bios errors

Comment: @Jos when I choose Ubuntu from Bios menu, it goes to the same dual boot menu. but I can't boot Ubuntu, when I choose ubuntu in dual boot, it goes to error screen: press any key to continue. then I have to hit exit and go to gnu grub, and only Windows can be loaded

Comment: The ubuntu entry is normally the full install. The live installer is a drive entry like UEFI:XXX where XXX is the name or label of the flash drive. Why downgrade to older copy? If newer hardware you may need newer install.